# after merging and extracting the BGR channel, compilation is successful,but there is a run-time error: ILLEGAL OPERATION

Tags: opencv, colors, bgr

I am [trying](http://answers.opencv.org/question/197410/is-it-possible-to-create-a-bgr-image-from-predefined-3-1-channel-image/?answer=197413#post-id-197413) to create 1 CV_8UC3 image from 3 different CV_8UC1 images that I already have, i.e I am trying to allocate the different single channel images that I already have into a single 1 Multi-Dimensional Image.
*Likely the below code worked flawlessly directly with 3-channel image but If am merging and extracting it comes up with a Runtime error*.
**ILLEGAL OPERATION**

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include<vector>
typedef cv::Vec3b Pixel;  //  correct


struct Operator {
    void operator ()(cv::Vec3b &pixel, const int * position) const 
    {    
            pixel[2]*=0.5; 
    }
}; 

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened())  
        return -1;
    cv::Mat frame1,frame2,for_each,cblue, cgreen, cred; 
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { cblue, cgreen, cred};
    for(;;)
    {
            cap >> frame1;    
            cvtColor(frame1, frame1, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
            frame1.convertTo(frame2,CV_8U);

            frame2.copyTo(cblue);
            frame2.copyTo(cgreen);
            frame2.copyTo(cred);

            cv::merge(channels, for_each);

            double t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
            for_each.forEach<Pixel>(Operator());
            t1 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
            std::cout<< "Parallel TEST time " << t1 << std::endl;

            cv::extractChannel (for_each, cblue, 0 );
            cv::imshow("cropped_BGR",frame1);
            cv::imshow("mod_BLUE",cblue);

           if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) 
           {
                std::cout << "esc key is pressed by user" <<std::endl;
                 break; 
           }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I am getting no idea from where this error is coming, any help will be really appreciated ,
TIA.

Comment: Can you show a call stack or at least the full message error ?

Comment: odroid@odroid:~/Desktop/is2/tia$ g++ -Wall  16_foreach_changedmaincode.cpp  -o op16 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
odroid@odroid:~/Desktop/is2/tia$ ./op16 

(process:2590): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:08.482: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
Illegal instruction @Sunreef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem:

When you do this:

```
cv::Mat frame1,frame2,for_each,cblue, cgreen, cred; 
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { cblue, cgreen, cred};
```

`channels` will have a shallow copy of the `cv::Mat` `cblue`, `cgreen` and  `cred`. This means, that they both will have the same headers with a data pointer that will point to the same place.

Then you do:

```
frame2.copyTo(cblue);
frame2.copyTo(cgreen);
frame2.copyTo(cred);
```

which does a deep copy of frame2 to each of the cv::Mat. The documentation of [`copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=clone#mat-copyto) says:

> **m –** Destination matrix. If it does not have a proper size or type
>   before the operation, it is reallocated.

This means, the pointer to data will change, however it won't change to the cv::Mat inside the vector, they will still point to `nullptr` but `cblue`, `cgreen` and `cred` will point to the other place.

I tested it with this code:

```
  cv::Mat frame(500, 500, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(111));
  cv::Mat frame1, frame2, cblue, cgreen, cred;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> channels{ cblue, cgreen, cred };
  // at this point all data members of mat will point to nullptr except frame
  cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  frame.convertTo(frame2, CV_8U);

  frame2.copyTo(cblue);
  frame2.copyTo(cgreen);
  frame2.copyTo(cred);

  // at this point all point to another place except the ones inside the vector
```

## Possible solutions:

1) Create references and not copies:

```
  cv::Mat frame1, frame2;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);
  cv::Mat& cblue = channels[0], &cgreen=channels[1], &cred=channels[2];
```

---

2) Use the channels directly instead of using other variables

```
        frame2.copyTo(channels[0]);
        frame2.copyTo(channels[1]);
        frame2.copyTo(channels[2]);
```

---

3) Create the vector inside the loop

```
        frame2.copyTo(cblue);
        frame2.copyTo(cgreen);
        frame2.copyTo(cred);
        std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { cblue, cgreen, cred};
        cv::merge(channels, for_each);
```

---

4) Your code is equivalent to:

```
cvtColor(frame1, frame1, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(frame1, for_each, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
```

This will create a 3 channel image of the grey values, which is basically a copy of the grey mat in each channel...

---

5) One more thing:

```
frame1.convertTo(frame2,CV_8U);
```

This is not necessary, because it is already a `CV_8U` mat, because the previous instruction converted it to greyscale which is `CV_8U` and then you can even create a vector there without doing deep copy (it will deep copy to for_each).

```
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { frame1, frame1, frame1};
    cv::merge(channels, for_each);
```

---

And one additional thing, not related to the error:

```
        cv::extractChannel (for_each, cblue, 0 );
        cv::imshow("cropped_BGR",frame1);
        cv::imshow("mod_BLUE",cblue);
```

will display exactly the same image :) or should at least.

Comment: Nice, detailed, informative, constructive answer! Keep them going. By the way, you can add a rule (horizontal line across page) to separate topics with three dashes `---`.

Comment: By the way, if you upvote questions that you answer from new users, not only does it encourage them towards sticking around on Stack Ovetflow, but it also means they can upvote, as well as accept, your brilliant answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, one of the best replies. Thank you very much !!!

**sol3** : it worked perfectly

```
double t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { cblue, cgreen, cred};
    cv::merge(channels, for_each);
    for_each.forEach<Pixel>(Operator());
    cv::extractChannel (for_each, cblue, 2 );
t1 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
std::cout<< "Parallel TEST time " << t1 << std::endl;
```

**sol1**: however it is still giving me

> error: 'class std::vector' has no member named 'forEach'
>            channels.forEach(Operator());
>                     ^~~~~~~ 16_vector_foreach_changedmaincode.cpp:54:31: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
>            channels.forEach(Operator());

my intention was to

```
    frame2.copyTo(cblue);
    frame2.copyTo(cgreen);
    frame2.copyTo(cred);

double t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    //std::vector<cv::Mat> channels { cblue, cgreen, cred};
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);
    cv::Mat& cblue = channels[0], &cgreen=channels[1], &cred=channels[2];
    //cv::merge(channels, for_each);
    channels.forEach<Pixel>(Operator());
    cv::extractChannel (channels, cblue, 2 );
t1 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
std::cout<< "Parallel TEST time " << t1 << std::endl;
```

do I have to use the merge operator here also ?? @api55